# Java MySQL JDBC Memory Leak

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, memory-leaks

Ok, so I have this program with many (~300) threads, each of which communicates with a central database. I create a global connection to the DB, and then each thread goes about its business creating statements and executing them.

Somewhere along the way, I have a massive memory leak. After analyzing the heap dump, I see that the com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection object is 70 MB, because it has 800,000 items in "openStatements" (a hash map). Somewhere it's not properly closing the statements that I create, but I cannot for the life of me figure out where (every single time I open one, I close it as well). Any ideas why this might be occurring?

Comment: do you mean 300 threads use the same connection? If that's so, better consider creating a connection pool.

Comment: I suggest you verify that you are closing the ResultSets AND the Statements AND the Connections. Maybe it'll help.

Comment: We could throw darts at a dartboard with possible things wrong, but without showing some code ... that's pretty much all we can do.

Comment: "a global connection" doesn't sound good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know unless MySQL says so, JDBC Connections are NOT thread safe. You CANNOT share them across threads, unless you use a connection pool. In addition as pointed out you should be try/finally guaranteeing all statements, result sets, and connections are closed.

Comment: Everything is try/finally closed. I'll look into this connection pooling though.

Comment: Cool. If you use C3P0 (and maybe others) it has a debugging mode that will spit out stacktraces of the acquiring connector if the connection is not returned in a specified time. A quick and easy way to trace many leaks

Comment: I've just seen that you can do try catch with resources since Java 7: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 29):

I had exactly the same problem. I needed to keep 1 connection active for 3 threads and at the same time every thread had to execute a lot of statements (the order of 100k). I was very careful and I closed every statement and every resultset using a try....finally... algorithm. This way, even if the code failed in some way, the statement and the resultset were always closed. After running the code for 8 hours I was suprised to find that the necessary memory went from the initial 35MB to 500MB. I generated a dump of the memory and I analyzed it with Mat Analyzer from Eclipse. It turned out that one com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection object was taking 445MB of memory keeping alive some openStatements objects wich in turn kept alive aroun 135k hashmap entries, probably from all the resultsets. So it seems that even if you close all you statements and resultsets, if you do not close the connection, it keeps references to them and the GarbageCollector can't free the resources.

**My solution**: after a long search I found this statement from the guys at MySQL:

"A quick test is to add "**dontTrackOpenResources=true**" to your JDBC URL. If the memory leak
goes away, some code path in your application isn't closing statements and result sets."

Here is the link: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=5022. So I tried that and guess what? After 8 hours I was around 40MB of memory required, for the same database operations.
Maybe a connection pool would be advisible, but if that's not an option, this is the next best thing I came around.

Answer (score 0):

Once upon a time, whenever my code saw "server went away," it opened a new DB connection. If the error happened in the right (wrong!) place, I was left with some non-free()d orphan memory hanging around. Could something like this account for what you are seeing? How are you handling errors?

Comment: I have a single connection object, and each time it gets a new statement it checks to see if it's still open/valid. if not, it makes sure the old one is actually closed and then overwrites it with a new one. Even if that was causing the leak, the fact that the heap dump analysis shows 800,000 items in the "openStatements" hash map leads me to believe it may be more about something to do with statements than the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code (which I'm sure is massive), you should really consider some sort of more formal thread pooling mechanism, such as Apache Commons pool framework, Spring's JDBC framework, and others. IMHO, this is a much simpler approach, since someone else has already figured out how to effectively manage these types of situations.