# Java - Tomcat GC won't free up.. always cause crash, can't find any memory leak

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection, jvm, out-of-memory

I have few issues with my tomcat application.
I'm using a linux server with 1024M memory.
I deploy my app on the tomcat, and everything working great.
Recently i notice that the 'Tenured Gen' heap memory not free up when it should...
It reach 99% and then crash tomcat..
I check my application with VisualVM, and the same result.
it fill up the memory and the 'Old Gen' never free up.

This is when the application run few minutes with no request:

IMG: [Everything looks normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXnjB.png)

And when I start to send requests with 200 Thread on a loop
this what happened:

IMG: [all memories are full](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05ffY.png)

So then I check data on the MAT, and this is my result:

IMG: [look like a memory leak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHaG6.png)

IMG: [Problem with the sql jdbc?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqv9x.jpg)

IMG: [Can't understand what is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgrBz.jpg)

this is my `ConnectionPool class`:

```
public class ConnectionPool {

    private static ConnectionPool singleton = null; 

    private ArrayList<Connection> freeConnections; 
    private ArrayList<Connection> allConnections; 
    private int MAX_CONNECTIONS = 1;

    private final String shema = "Topic";

    private final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+shema+"?  autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
    private final String username = "root";
    private final String password = "password";




    public static ConnectionPool getInstance(){
        if (singleton == null)
        {
            synchronized (ConnectionPool.class) {
                if (singleton == null){
                    System.out.println("ConnectionPool get instance");
                    try {
                        singleton = new ConnectionPool();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } //this will invoke the constructor
                }
            }
        }
        return singleton;
    }

    private ConnectionPool() throws Exception {

        freeConnections = new ArrayList<Connection>();
        allConnections = new ArrayList<Connection>();
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++) {
            try {
                addNewConnection();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
    private void addNewConnection() throws SQLException {
        try {

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username,  password);
            freeConnections.add(conn);
            allConnections.add(conn);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
    public Connection getConnection() 
    {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (freeConnections) {

                if (freeConnections.size() != 0) { // free connection is  available 
                    Connection conn = freeConnections.get(0);
                    freeConnections.remove(0);
                    try {
                        conn.setAutoCommit(true);
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return conn;
                }
                try {
                    freeConnections.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

    }
    public void returnConnection(Connection conn)
    {
        if (null == conn) { // ignore invalid value
            return;
        }
        if (!allConnections.contains(conn)) {
            return;
        }
        synchronized (freeConnections) {

            if (freeConnections.contains(conn)) {
                return;
            }
            freeConnections.add(conn);
            freeConnections.notifyAll();
            return;
        }
    }
    public void closeAllconnections()
    {
        for (Connection conn : allConnections) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("ConnectionPool all connection closed");
        deregisterDriver();
    }
    public void deregisterDriver() {
        try {
            java.sql.Driver driver = DriverManager.getDriver(url);
            DriverManager.deregisterDriver(driver);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        System.out.println("ConnectionPool deregister driver");

    }
}
```

Please help me to understand what is wrong and explain me.

1.Why the GC won't free up or why he can't do his job?

2.Is something wrong with my `ConnectionPool Class`?

3.why tomcat not saying anything about `OutOfMemoryException` in my logs(just crashing)?

Comment: A server with only 1Gb is quite small, the OS itself & other service (other than jvm) also need to use memory, and what is the jvm setting for `-Xms` and `-Xmx`?

Comment: I tried few memory size, now is -Xms256M -Xmx512M

Comment: Do a `top` before start your jvm, to check does it have enough memory in the os for the jvm.

Comment: When I tried -Xms512M -Xms1024M it crash when the 'Tenured Gen' is about 50%-70%

Comment: The server only have 1Gb memory, obviously you should set -Xms and -Xmx smaller. If you set `-Xms1024M` it can't start for sure, since it can't allocate that much memory.

Comment: How to do the 'top' or check if 1GB is enough?

Comment: On linux, you can do that with a terminal. On windows, start you task manager. In either case, check how much memory is free.

Comment: I got it, but my main question was why the gc not free up the old memory, it can reach 512M at least before its full, I want the gc to free up some memory and keep the application alive

Comment: When I used the VisualVM with my Mac, I have set 2GB just for the tomcat application, and then also the gc won't free up memory (https://i.stack.imgur.com/05ffY.png )

Comment: GC is an expensive operation, jvm won't do it unless necessary, gc occurs when one of the areas in jvm is almost full. If you tell jvm it can use up to 512M memory, then it will try to make use of it, and when it try to allocate it, it will crash, since the system have not enough memory to allocate any more. If it can't free space when it's full, then there probably has memory leak.

Comment: Throw your connection pool away and use the one from Apache: DBCP. There is no reason to reinvent this wheel.

Comment: So do you think if I buy a bigger server the problem will be resolved? And why MAT tell me that I have a memory leak? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHaG6.png)

Comment: EJP, Ok I will try it.. and update how is going

Comment: *"So do you think if I buy a bigger server the problem will be resolved?"* Nope.  *"And why MAT tell me that I have a memory leak?"* Because you probably do have a memory leak.  But the solution is to eliminate the most likely cause ... which is your connection pool implementation.

Comment: To be specific, the collection `allConnections` serves no useful purpose in your code, except that in `closeAllConnections()` it is traversed *but never cleared*, which is the site of at least one leak in this code. You can avoid elementary mistakes like this by never causing them in the first place. You don't need a `closeAllConections()` method; you don't need an `allConnections` collection; and you certainly don't need a connection pool implementation with its own API when working implementations exist that merely implement the existing `Connection` interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the connection details, apparently you have 10 connections and each retains cca 66 MB if the heap summing up to 660 MB required RAM.

I don't know what data you select, however when returning a connection you may want to close all resultsets and statements (why are you creating your own pool? dbcp, c3p0 or commons-pool ain't good enough? for learning?) and seems it may be not enough. I really don't know what the pool implementations do to release all resources properly.

And seems it is not so straightforward to share open connections between multiple threads [Java MySQL JDBC Memory Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765990/java-mysql-jdbc-memory-leak) so I would suggest to use a working pool solution (dbcp)

Comment: Thank you, dbcp work great memory now can free up.. thank you